# "Bouncing" an openVPN connection through/over/across another host

Tags: networking, vpn, port-forwarding, openvpn, iptables

One of the locations I work from/at is blocking all traffic to "commonly known" VPN services, including the VPN service I use.

I would now like to "bounce" the openVPN traffic through/across/over my own VPS (the IP of which is not blocked) to my VPN service - and back. Like so:

`|me| <-UDP-> |my VPS| <-UDP-> |VPN service|` so that a virtual/logical connection like this is initiated: `|me| <-UDP-> |VPN service|`.

I have the following `iptables` rules at work (`196.196.yyy.yyy` is my VPN provider's server IP):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -i venet0:0 --dport 1194 -j DNAT --to-destination 196.196.yyy.yyy:1194
iptables -A FORWARD -p udp -d 196.196.yyy.yyy --dport 1194 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i venet0:0 --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 196.196.yyy.yyy:443
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 196.196.yyy.yyy --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Yet, `openvpn` cannot establish a connection (`50.3.xxx.xxx` is my VPS's IP address):

```
$ sudo /some/dir/sbin/openvpn --config /some/dir/hoppingvpntcp.ovpn --verb 6
(...)
Fri Sep 28 14:48:57 2018 us=785094 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]50.3.xxx.xxx:443 [nonblock]
Fri Sep 28 14:48:58 2018 us=785837 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]50.3.xxx.xxx:443
Fri Sep 28 14:48:58 2018 us=785887 TCP_CLIENT link local: (not bound)
Fri Sep 28 14:48:58 2018 us=785908 TCP_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]50.3.xxx.xxx:443
Fri Sep 28 14:48:58 2018 us=786112 TCP_CLIENT WRITE [86] to [AF_INET]50.3.xxx.xxx:443: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_CLIENT_V2 kid=0 pid=[ #1 ] [ ] pid=0 DATA len=0
Fri Sep 28 14:48:58 2018 us=814033 Connection reset, restarting [0]
Fri Sep 28 14:48:58 2018 us=814157 TCP/UDP: Closing socket
Fri Sep 28 14:48:58 2018 us=814272 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
Fri Sep 28 14:48:58 2018 us=814373 Restart pause, 5 second(s)
^CFri Sep 28 14:49:01 2018 us=543743 SIGINT[hard,init_instance] received, process exiting
$
```

(full paste [here](https://pastebin.com/bCm2rJdX)).

Connecting directly (from another location of course, but the above is also tested from an open location) works, so the inner workings of the config and the network on both endpoints seem to be fine.

Comment: Why not just set up an OpenVPN server on your VPS? // Because the source address remains unchanged, this cannot work. Redirecting traffic is hard.

Comment: Find a VPN service that is not "commonly known". There are heaps of such services and they are not that costly.